# How do I pass a null value to a SqlDataSource that is using a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

Using .NET 4 and C#. All of these throw an error:

```
sdsTypeinfo.SelectParameters.Add("@TypeCode", DbType.Boolean, DBNull.Value);

sdsTypeinfo.SelectParameters.Add("@TypeCode", DBNull.Value);

sdsTypeinfo.SelectParameters.Add("@TypeCode", null);

sdsTypeinfo.SelectParameters.Add("@TypeCode", "");
```

The error indicates that the procedure is not getting any value at all.

```
Procedure or function 'Typeinfo' expects parameter '@TypeCode', which was not supplied.
```

**Answer**

You don't need the @ in the name of the parameter. This is different than adding parameters when calling the stored procedure using a SqlCommand, in which case you want something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeCode", DBNull.Value);
```

Also, DBNull.value is an acceptable parameter in the above, but the accepted NULL value when adding SelectParameters to an SqlDataSource is simply "null".

Comment: What kind of error does it throw? On the Sql server side or client side? What's exactly the error message?

Comment: Is it a typo?  The error expects the parameter to be called `@pTypeCode` and you are passing in `@TypeCode`...

Answer (score 1):

There should be an option when adding a parameter to convert empty string to null.

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lstCategories" Name="ProductSubcategoryID" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Since you're using a stored procedure, you'll want to make the parameter optional:

```
@SomeParm INT = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this...

```
    string x = null;
command.Parameters.AddParameter(
     new SqlParameter("@column", (object)x ?? DBNull.Value);
```

would give you a parm with a value of DBNull.Value, but

```
string x = "A String";
command.Parameters.AddParameter(
     new SqlParameter("@column", (object)x ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedure set the parameter to have a value eg

```
@TypeCode = ''
```

or if its an int

```
@typecode = 1
```

etc you get the idea.

Comment: I have no control over the stored procedure.